# left-edge swipe in WKInterfaceController is hangs the UI in Apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

I have a serious issue related to left-edge swipe in `WKInterfaceController`.

When I do left-edge swipe two times in `WKInterfaceController` from root interface controller then my application hangs the UI.

For Example I have A, B, C three `WKInterfaceController` when I do two time left-edge swipe from A interface controller after that I tap a button to push my interface controller from A to B. So my B interface controller never present in the screen. I checked `willActivate` is getting called on B but the `didDeactivate` method of A never called.

Once I go in background and then come back in foreground I can able to see B interface controller.

I am using below code to push my controller from A to B:

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"B" context:nil];
```

After that I tried `segue` to do the same. but this is happening with `segue` as well.

Please let me know if someone have the same issue or knows relevant solutions or suggestion for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meet the same issue.
And I write a very simple demo here https://github.com/ddrdjboy/AppleWatchLeftSwipeIssueDemo

Step:

1. Click app icon and launch the app(back to foreground).
2. Click "Hello World~" table row it will push to a detail screen.
3. Click back button or swipe left. (sometime you can ignore this step, it ok.)
4. Click digital crown to the apple watch main screen.

Repeat Step 1-4 more than 30 times (from my experience) it will occur randomly.

When bug occurred:
Click "Hello World~" table row, no effect. 
Click back button on the left top no effect.
Only left-edge-swipe can rescue. When I swipe left, the first screen will animate from right to left and second screen will come in. Very very strange.

I raised a bug and wait for Apple's response.